# C# Wait for javascript to finish before retrieving HTML Console Application

Tags: c#, console-application

There are pages I'm trying to get the HTML for but I need javascript to finish doing it's thing before I get the HTML.

I was reading online and people say to put insert an IE inside your form but I'm doing this with a console application.

So how could I get the HTML for a site after the Javascript finishes loading if I'm coding this in a console application?

Comment: How are you GETting the url? Does the client you're using even run the javascript at all?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're using something like [HttpClient](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.http.httpclient%28v=vs.118%29.aspx) you won't be able to execute any JavaScript because all it does is HTTP-GETing the website without executing any scripts.

You could take a look at browser automation tools like e.g. [SeleniumHQ](http://www.seleniumhq.org/) to get that done.